# How exactly does a tuple go into a particular bucket?

Tags: javascript, tuples, hashtable, bucket

I was trying to implement a Hash Table code, but I was confused with the overall concept.
I understand that there is a storage, and in it, there are a set number of buckets. There can be more than one tuple in a bucket based on how many buckets I set at first.

But what I don't understand is,
how do you know which key value pair goes into which bucket in a hash table?
I wasn't sure if it's just random, or if there is some kind of rule that I have to follow.

-Sorry for being a newbie.

Comment: This can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F95z5Wxd9ks

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! This video helped :)